# how to set a fields from a url sharepoint 2010

Tags: url, sharepoint-2010

I have a list called Case,in the Case form i have the folowing hyper link

http://appserver/Lists/Hearings/Item/newifs.aspx?List=928323ea%2Deace%2D4220%2D845c%2D84871b4f00a8&=&Case_x0020_Number=100000

if you can see at the end of the url I have the item Case Number,what I want is to make the Hearing add new form to have the value of 10000 at the Case Number

so the user don't need to re-enter the value.

but when I click that link it open the new form thing but the field corresponding to that value is blank.

Note : from the share point it self the Case Number of the Hearing is  lookup from the Case Number.

is there away to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You say

> but when I click that link it open the new form thing but the field corresponding to that value is blank.

This happens when you click the hyperlink directly from the list view?

If you want your "Case number" field to populate dynamically you should create a *calculated* column, and use a formula to take the current "Case number" for the selected item. After that you can create a Hyperlink in InfoPath and navigate from the item's edit screen...

The formula for the *calculated* column should be something like this:

```
=("LocationToNavigate?queryStringParameter="&ListFiedName)
```

Comment: if you read my post again you will see that I Have created the url already. now what i want is how to pull those values in the url onto the form of the hearings

Comment: If I understood well this post will solve your problem: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/10/29/setting-sharepoint-form-fields-using-query-string-variables-without-using.aspx

or something similar here:
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=107